# Ошибка открытия файла по адресу .../go-buildXXXXXXX/... при попытке компиляции (golang)

Tags: windows, golang, build

При попытки компиляции или создания временного файла:

```
go build -o xx
go run main.go
```

Выдается ошибка:

```
open C:\Users\Nikita\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build122659818\b001\exe\main.exe: The
 system cannot find the file specified.
```

Версия go:

```
 go version go1.10.8 windows/amd64
```

Настройки:

```
C:\Go\workspace\src\hello>go env
set GOARCH=amd64
set GOBIN=
set GOCACHE=C:\Users\Nikita\AppData\Local\go-build
set GOEXE=.exe
set GOHOSTARCH=amd64
set GOHOSTOS=windows
set GOOS=windows
set GOPATH=C:\go\workspace
set GORACE=
set GOROOT=C:\Go
set GOTMPDIR=
set GOTOOLDIR=C:\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64
set GCCGO=gccgo
set CC=gcc
set CXX=g++
set CGO_ENABLED=1
set CGO_CFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_CPPFLAGS=
set CGO_CXXFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_FFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_LDFLAGS=-g -O2
set PKG_CONFIG=pkg-config
set GOGCCFLAGS=-m64 -mthreads -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=C:\Users\Nik
ita\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build276669498=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches
```

Сам файл:

```
package main
import "fmt"
func main() {
    fmt.Println("hello world")
}
```

Версия windows:

```
Win 7 SP1
```

Все работало и вдруг начало выдавать такую ошибку.

Comment: Если _Шindows,_ то антивирус.  Ну и да, у вас версия го древняя.

Comment: Go - переставлял на старую, думал может из за этого. Удалил всё ненужное ПО (в том числе) антивирус, заработало.... Спасибо...

Comment: Напишите, пожалуйста, ответ.  Чтобы остальным было видно возможное решение проблемы.